# supporting a new format character in python's struct.pack_into

Tags: python, struct, encoding, binary, protocol-buffers

I have a python [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) format string that I'd like to split up over multiple calls to `struct.pack_into`, like so:

```
buff = bytearray()
fmt = "!BBi4sVi3s"
args = [1, 0, 4, "abcd", 6, 3, "abc"]
offset = 0
fmt_parts = fmt.split("V")
for fmt_part in fmt_parts:
    struct.pack_into(fmt_part, buff, offset, *args)
    offset += struct.calcsize(fmt_part)
```

This doesn't work, because the `args` list is passed in its entirety each time through the loop, though each call will only care about a sublist of that list.

**Is there a way, given a format string, to figure out exactly how many arguments from the `args` list will be consumed by a call to `struct.pack_into` using that format string?** It's also important that the solution is as performant as possible.

I've tried something like this

```
# every format char that doesn't consume an arg, per the struct docs
NOARG_STRUCT_FMTS = re.compile(r'[^xcbB\?hHiIlLqQfdspP]')
stripped_fmt_part = re.sub(NOARG_STRUCT_FMTS, '', fmt_part)
part_args = [args.pop(0) for _ in range(len(stripped_fmt_part))]
```

but it's possible that this approach is unreliable or slower than optimal.

Additional context: I'm trying to add a custom format character `V` to the functionality of `struct.pack_into` that causes the argument to be encoded as a [`varint`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints). I'm aware that there are existing python implementations of `varint` encoding/decoding, but I'd like to make my own that's compatible with the interface defined by `struct.pack_into`, which I haven't seen in the community.